# Start virtual machine with Qemu (in the command line)

Tags: qemu

I am using KVM in Fedora 13. I can use Virtual machine monitor to run the Guest OS. My Guest Machine works fine and fast while I open it through Virtual-Machine-Monitor. But when I try to open Guest through the command line, my guest OS becomes extremely slow. It does not even show me the activity bar. I use the following command to run Guest:

```
qemu fedora.img -m 1024
```

I need to run my Guest through command possibly because I can pass a lot of parameters to the Qemu.

Answer (score 2):

Well I am replying pretty late. Try using --enable-kvm flag along with the command. By default qemu goes for binary translation alone which slows it down a bit. If you use the --enable-kvm flag, the hardware virtualization features are utilized which would speed it up

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your machine monitor might be using a more detailed configuration that results in better performance.  If you can see what command it is invoking (try ps -Af) or view the configuration files, that might help.

QEMU can be slow when running in emulation mode, without hardware acceleration.  The default from the command line is to run emulation mode.

Some commands you could add to your command line:
-enable-kvm
-cpu host